# Value overwriting in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am getting different values when I am printing it with printf. I tried a lot to solve this problem. But I didn't get how to solve this-
**Here are the few lines of code-**

```
#Dymically allocated memory-
 char **child = (char **)malloc(totalRows * sizeof(*child));

 int i=0;
 while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
        {
                child[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(row[1]) + 1);
                child[i]=strdup(row[1]);
                printf("%u %s \n",  &child[i], child[i]);
                i++;
       }

int j=0;
for (j; j<i; j++)
     printf("%u %s \n",  &child[j], child[j]);
```

**Output is**

```
7127200 1111 
7127208 111111vv 
7127216 111111sd 
7127224 111111en 
7127232 111113nk 
7127240 111113t3 

7127200 1111 
7127208 1111      //..Here I am getting different value- 
7127216 111111sd 
7127224 111111en 
7127232 111113nk 
7127240 111113t3
```

Comment: Why are you calling assigning the return value of `malloc` and then `strdup` to the same variable? [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) calls `malloc` internally.

Comment: so, exacty what should be the code ? actually I tried everything to solve this

Comment: Wouldn't it be more helpful to print the address stored to `child[i/j]`? Then you could differentiate between that pointer changing and the thing it points to changing.

Comment: Also, use `%p` for printing pointers. They're addresses - view them in hex.

Comment: Have you made sure that `i` never gets bigger than `totalRows`? Other than that the code you're showing shouldn't have any problems except the memory leak because of the malloc+strdup and unnecessary casts of the return value from malloc and using %u to print pointers, none of which should cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @Art value of i will not cross totalRows.

Comment: @user2794235 Then I can say with a high level of confidence that the problem is not in the code shown here. Make a minimal compilable example and test from there. If you can't do that, try running your program under valgrind or some other memory error detection tool.

Comment: What's the declaration of row? And you cannot print addresses with `%u` (that's undefined behavior). You must use `%p` and cast the argument for it to a `void *`.

Comment: @Jens: could that last point be the actual problem here? `sizeof(void *) != sizeof(uint)`?

Comment: @Jongware Unlikely, but yes, undefined is undefined is undefined. More likely, to speculate, we're not seeing actual complete code. I suspect some code is missing between the two output loops that messes with the child[] memory.

Answer (score 0):

i would try few things here:

bzero child

remove                 child[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(row[1]) + 1);
 //as you are already allocated memory using strdup

free child[i]

char **child = (char **)malloc(totalRows * sizeof(char *)); // child is a pointer to an array of char * pointer

Let me know if this works for you